# ransomware threat, what to do now?

Tags: ransomware

yesterday one of my client's system started to popping this message, is the threat legit, what options do I have to restore [image]

Comment: Reinstall os, restore data from backup

Comment: This is not a "threat". You have been infected with ransomware.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation. will reinstall the os or better enough scrap the harddisk.